# Store result of view as a variable and then call it in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Is something like this possible in SQL server?

```
DECLARE @SQL int  
SET @SQL = (CREATE VIEW AS SELECT *
        FROM .....
        JOIN.....)

EXEC @SQL

SELECT * FROM 

@SQL

LEFT JOIN.....
ON....
```

I want to join on the result of a view.

And then to actually select the variables such as

```
join ..... on @SQL.No = ......
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do. Why do you need a variable (and why is this int?)

Comment: Im trying to join a table based upon the result of a view but have it in the same query

Comment: Are you familiar with CTEs? Do they do what you need? If not why not?

Comment: Would a regular join to the view, or even just a join to a subquery not work? Something like `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable LEFT JOIN myView ON myTable.myColumnId = myView.myColumnId` or `SELECT myColumn FROM myTable LEFT JOIN (SELECT myColumnId FROM myTable WHERE x=y) mySubQuery ON myTable.myColumnId = mySubQuery.myColumnId`

Comment: a subquery wont work because it has to be joined on the result of the whole view. I would normal just create anoter view with the code and join them but ive been asked to put it all in one query

Comment: Creating views on the fly is a fundamentally bad idea.  If a subquery won't work for one reason or another, then use temporary tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense.  Why would you want to create a view using dynamic SQL?  You can just create a view as:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT *
    FROM ..... JOIN
         .....;
```

You can then use the view in a query:

```
select . . .
from my_view join
     . . .
```

No dynamic SQL is required.

If you want a "temporary view" for a query, you can use a CTE or subquery.

Comment: i need to call the result of the view in the same query

Comment: That comment makes no sense.

Comment: Like in programming, how a function could calculate a sum and then you could call the result and use it in the same program

Comment: @RyanGadsdon . . . SQL is a 4th generation language.  The `SELECT` statement describes the result set, but not how to generate it.  Don't confuse SQL with procedural, object-oriented, or functional languages.

Comment: It was more a question of would this type of logic be possible in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) ,
        @viewName nvarchar(50) = 'MyView'

SET @SQL = ('CREATE VIEW ' +@viewName  +'AS SELECT *
            FROM .....
            JOIN.....')

 EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL

 SET @SQL = ('
 SELECT * FROM ' +  @viewName +'
 LEFT JOIN.....
 ON.... ')

 EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql
```

Comment: I have got this running but it returns nothing

Comment: before each exec sp_executeSQL run a select on @sql so you can see exactly what is inside.

Comment: are you using a table variable in one of your join ? if so you must pass it as a parameter to sp_executesql